# How to get same Random () data from MySQL in two documents at the same time?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, database, random

Right this is tough one for me and I can't figure it out. I have 2 **.php** files (one with iframe other with comment. so lets call them **iframe.php** and **comment.php** respectively).

In iframe.php file I get random url from database and put it as **src** of `<iframe>`:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT url FROM address_book ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1")
```

In comments.php file I get random url from same database table:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT comment FROM address_book ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1")
```

Then on **index.php** page I have button:

```
<button id="nextfLuky" onClick="viewNext();return false;">Randomize</button>
```

This button calls following javascript function that inserts  from iframe.php file into `<div id="iframe"></div>` (located in index.php page). And comment from comment.php file is also inserted in `<div id="comment"></div>` (Also located in index.php file)

And this is javascript called by `<button>`

```
function viewNext()
{
$("#iframe").load("iframe.php");
$("#coment").load("coment.php");
}
```

The problem is that I need to get url and comment that are related to each other from database (I can do it if I use one .php file, but I need to use two). And as I get them randomly in two different files they are not related to each other, when displayed in index.php file.

So how can I get url and comment that are related to each other if I get each one randomly in two different files?

**Addition: Database Table Structure**

```
______________________________________
id       |int(11)      |Auto Increment
______________________________________
url      |varchar(255)
______________________________________
comment  |text(1000)
______________________________________
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay if you prefer JQuery I am replacing the XmlHttp solution with one made with jquery. Check it out out how the information is passed, I think is not difficult to adjust it to your needs.

You only have to create a getUrl.php file to get the url (I have created one for testing purposes). **iframe.php and comment.php will remain intact**, *just make sure they get the random url from $_GET['url'].*

Again I notice this is a solution according to your current design, not a general or best one.

To test it, let's say this is index.php (**you only need the viewNext() from here** the other code is for testing):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

function viewNext()
{ 
$.get("getUrl.php",null, 
            function(responseText)
            {   $("#iframe").attr('src', 'iframe.php?url='+responseText); 
                $("#comment").load('comment.php','url='+responseText);
            }
);//load ends
}//viewNext ends

</script>
</head>
<body onload="viewNext()">
<input type=submit value=next id="mySubmit" onclick="viewNext()"><br>
<IFRAME  id="iframe" WIDTH=450 HEIGHT=100>
Ybrowser doesn't show IFRAME.  
</IFRAME>
<div id="comment"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then this is iframe.php (with testing code):

```
<?PHP
echo 'Hello from <font color=red>iframe.php</font> I got the url, here it is:<br>
<font color=blue>',$_GET['url'],'</font>';
?>
```

Then this is comment.php (with testing code):

```
<?PHP
echo 'Hello from comment.php I got the url, here it is:<br>
<font color=blue>',$_GET['url'],'</font>';
?
```

And finally getUrl.php (copy paste -or include- your code to get random url here and just echo it!):

```
<?PHP
echo 'http://www.url',rand(1,9999),'.com';
?>
```

Comment: Ok sorry my fault, I didn't make my self clear ))) So first of all I load up index.php and there I have button which executes iframe.php and coment.php via javascript I mentioned in my question. I can get url in index.php as it executes before two other pages, but I need new random url each time when user clicks <button> (which executes iframe.php and coment.php files)

Comment: Ufff a lot of stuff there ))) alright I give it a shot, but I will leave this topic for a while incase someone has jQuery solution as my website is based on it. Thank you )))